# git push error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500

Tags: git

When I want to push some files, I get the following error. Just some files look like this.

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 37, done.
Counting objects: 100% (37/37), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Writing objects: 100% (26/26), 7.62 KiB | 1.52 MiB/s, done.
Total 26 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

The following command did not help.

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

This did not help either.

```
git gc
git fsck
```

Comment: Check the server logs for why it threw a 500

Comment: See [MDN: HTTP 500 docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500). HTTP 500 is a generic error for which you have to consult the log files of the server. Usually it is an error with server resources (RAM, disk space, etc.) but it can also be an application error.

Comment: @DanielW. I do not know how to check. I do not access to server.

Comment: @PeterKrebs If it is for server resources, so why do only some files get this error?

Comment: Could this explain error 500? ```fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly```

Comment: Make sure you have an up to date version of git and ask the person who controls the server to have a look into the logs and to make sure their server software is up to date. You could also try alternative transport, like git over ssh.

Comment: @DanielW. I updated the git bash but it did not work.

Comment: @alim The error happens on the server, not on your computer. The error `the remote end hung up unexpectedly` is displayed because of the HTTP 500, it does not cause the error.

Answer (score 4):

> I do not know how to check. I do not access to server.

That is the actual issue, because the server is actively erroring on its side.

If said server was, for instance, github.com, you would have access to [`githubstatus.com`](https://www.githubstatus.com/) in order to check what is going on.

But if it is an on-premise Git repository hosting service (a [self-managed GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/self-managed/feature-comparison/) or a [Gitea](https://gitea.com/)), then you need to contact the administrator, and report this incident.

---

The [OP ali m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17781919/ali-m) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508936/git-push-error-rpc-failed-http-500-curl-22-the-requested-url-returned-error-5#comment124639057_70509472):

> We use Azure DevOps.

Indeed: [`status.dev.azure.com/_history`](https://status.dev.azure.com/_history) shows:

"[Availability Degradation in South India.](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/280157666)"

> The issue is now fully mitigated. Our engineers will be investigating this further to learn from and reduce the risk of potential recurrences.
> We apologize for the impact this had on our customers.

So try again, and see if the issue persists.

Comment: We use Azure DevOps.

Comment: @alim I have included your comment for more visibility, and updated the answer.

Comment: What can I do now to push my files?

Comment: The interesting thing is that only some files get this error and I have no problem with push other files when I change them.

Comment: @alim Are those files too big? Are they binaries?

Comment: I added and pushed the files one by one and some of the files get this error. For example, when I want to push only one of the files that has only 4 lines of code, it gets this error. It is css file.

Comment: @alim Are you in the South India region? Meaning, could you still be affected with the incident mentioned in the answer?

Comment: No. I am not South India region.